# Introducir en archivo el contenido de una variable

Tags: c

Como puedo introducir en un archivo una string pasada por terminal?

```
fp=fopen("personas.txt","a");
printf("Introduce tu nombre:\n");
scanf("%s",&nombre);
```

Es decir, que tengo que hacer para meter en un archivo el contenido de la variable nombre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta sería la forma de Introducir en archivo el contenido de una variable
 tomando de base tu código inicial, se agregan comentarios en el código :

```
int main () {
    char texto[20];
   //abre archivo.
    FILE *f = fopen("personas.txt", "w"); //permisos de escritura.
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al abrir archivo!\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
      printf("Introduce tu nombre:\n");
      //obtiene palabra introducida desde teclado.
      scanf("%s", nombre);        
      fprintf(f, "Se introdujo el nombre: %s\n", nombre);
      //cierra archivo.
      fclose(f);
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para escribir carácter a carácter existe la función `fputc (int c, File stream)`
Siendo c el carácter y stream el fichero. Para esto deberás recorrer el string con un bucle, por ejemplo:

```
char texto[]="Gandalf";

char *p;

int longitud=0;

p = texto;

while (*p != '\0') {
    longitud++;
    fputc( *p, fichero );
    p++;            /* Vamos a la siguiente letra */
}`
```

Recuerda cerrar el Stream al terminar la operacion con `fclose (File stream)`

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen ( "fichero.txt", "r+" );
printf("Introduce tu nombre:\n");
scanf("%s",&nombre);
fputs( nombre, fp );
fclose ( fp );
return 0;
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace el código?

Comment: Por favor, añade algo de explicación al código.

Comment: El programa lo que hace es introducir personas en un archivo hasta que yo quiera que acabe.